# Возврат ещё несуществующей переменной

Tags: функции, javascript, node.js

Здравствуйте. Пишу свой первый модуль для node js и столкнулся с такой проблемой:
В конце нашего модуля мы передаём module.exports, содержащий набор функций.
Но если функция определится только через несколько сек.?
У меня она определяется при открытии serialPort.

---

Для тех, кто не понял, я подготовил похожую ситуация на обычном js:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iliailia1212/qpn5sL8f/1/)
Функция возвращает ещё несуществующую переменную.
Возможно, кто-то предложит поставить таймер и на вызов этой функции, но мне этот вариант не подходит.

Comment: Спинным мозгом чувствую, что это нечто из [этой оперы](http://hashcode.ru/questions/401656#401681). Ваша несуществующая переменная `test_fun` стала в одночасье глобальной. Может быть её стоит где-нибудь всё-таки объявить через `var`?

Comment: @romeo, попробовал, дело не в этом. На момент return ей ещё не присвоено нужно значение. Тут даже всё логически понятно.

Comment: Если ее еще не существует, то появляется вопрос: а нужно ли ее вообще возвращать? Второй важный вопрос: почему *функция* (не переменная, а блок кода, часть функционала) появляется только при каком-то событии?

Всегда можно вернуть геттер, который стрельнет исключением, если программа еще не готова к его вызову.

Comment: @Etki, Смотрите, расскажу вам подробно всю ситуацию. Я пишу API для работы с модулем serialPort, для своих нужд. В модуле он: открывает соединение с TTY через serialPort и через EventEmitter предоставляет набор функция для отправки\принятий данных. Но пока событие 'open' у serialPort не сработает, мы не можем не принимать, не отправлять данные (пока он не подключится к TTY).  Мне нужно дождаться события 'open' и потом только выполнять все операции с данным модулем. На jsfiddle я привёл пример подобно ситуации.

Comment: @Mr_Epic, ны jsfiddle абсолютно несвязанный пример, который, как вам кажется, является единственно верным вариантом, в то время как он им ни разу не является. Если мы возьмем любой клиент API, то он тоже не имеет коннекта в момент подключения, но никогда не дописывается на ходу. Все, что вам нужно - это класс коннекта, который будет собственно и будет управлять активностью подключения. `new Connection(address)` - и только у полученного объекта будут методы приема/передачи данных, но они будут объявлены сразу же.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qpn5sL8f/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам, я так понимаю, нужен класс для подключения, реализующий callback. Условный псевдокод:

```
var Connection = function (port, on_connection_callback) {
    var is_connected = false;

    var connection = connect_to_tty(port);
    // Не знаю, как там устанавливается соединение и как называется метод,
    // но думаю вы разберетесь.
    connection.onopen = function () {
        is_connected = true;
        on_connection_callback()
    };

    this.send = function (message) {
        if (is_connected) // send
        else // raise error
    }
}

var connection = new Connection('/dev/tty1', function () {
    console.log('connection established!');
    connection.send('hello, world');
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, я надеялся, что есть решение без callback.

Comment: Как вы себе представляете решение без callback? Как передавать данные по несуществующему подключению?